# How to sort the string of date format in an array

Tags: javascript, angular

**Input**

```
var data = ["09 may 2015", "25 december 2015", "22 march 2015", "25 june 2016", "18 august 2015"];
```

**output**
22 March 2015,
09 May 2015,
18 August 2015,
25 December 2015,
25 jun 2016

Comment: Have you tried using `.sort()` and within the comparison using `new Date()` to get the actual dates? May be something like this: `const sortData = arr => arr.sort((a, b) => (new Date(a)) > (new Date(b)) ? 1 : -1); console.log(sortData(data));` - please try and share feedback if any problem.

Comment: Using sort will produce the wrong result 
09 may 2015
18 augest 2015
22 march 2015
25 december 2015
25 june 2016

Comment: @jsN00b its working thanks

Comment: The reason it does not give "wrong result" is because the sort-function uses `new Date()` to convert the string into a JavaScript `date` and then compares the date. If we directly compare the strings, it'll give results that you've correctly noted. BTW, welcome bro (vaazthukkal & nandri).

Comment: Can we write it without using new date method

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do so without `new Date()`. I'll try to post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Subtracting** `2` **dates** returns the difference between the two **dates** in **milliseconds** if `a` date is smaller than `b` returns negative values `a` will sorted to be a lower index than `b`.

```js
var data = ["09 may 2015", "25 december 2015", "22 march 2015", "25 june 2016", "18 august 2015"];


data.sort(function(a,b){
  return  new Date(a) - new Date(b);
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Mohammad Ali bhai, it is so good if you explain the function in brief. Thnx in advance.

Comment: @ShahzadBarkati Thanks for the query. I have added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, one simple solution would be to use `new Date()`. Since OP requested for a possible method without `new Date()`, the below solution may be able to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// set-up a map/object to map "january": "01", "february": "02", etc
const monthMap = Object.fromEntries(
  "january,february,march,april,may,june,july,august,september,october,november,december"
  .split(',').map(
    (month, idx) => ([month, idx.toString().padStart(2, '0')])
  )
);

// use the map/object to convert month into 2-char string
const monthToNum = m => m.toLowerCase() in monthMap ? monthMap[m.toLowerCase()] : '99';

// reformat date from dd MMM yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd
const reformatDate = dt => {
  const parts = dt.split(' ');
  return [parts[2], monthToNum(parts[1]), parts[0]].join('-');
};

// use the custom-made "reformat" method to sort
const sortData = arr => arr.sort((a, b) => reformatDate(a) > reformatDate(b) ? 1 : -1);

// actual data from OP's question
const data = ["09 may 2015", "25 december 2015", "22 march 2015", "25 june 2016", "18 august 2015"];

// invoke the sort-method and console.log the result
console.log(sortData(data));
```

**Explanation**

Comments have been added in-line within the code-snippet above. If any further questions, please use comments below.